# Is it possible to make the label attribute flexible in Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigationMain_fragment_profileFragment"
    android:name="com.test.fragments.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="luq281"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">

    <argument
        android:name="userId"
        app:argType="integer" />

    <argument
        android:name="username"
        app:argType="string" />

</fragment>
```

Is it possible to make the label attribute read the value from specific arguments such as the username argument?

I know how can I do it programmatically but I want to do it in XML itself.

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

To use username argument as label:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigationMain_fragment_profileFragment"
    android:name="com.test.fragments.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="{username}"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">

    <argument
        android:name="userId"
        app:argType="integer" />

    <argument
        android:name="username"
        app:argType="string" />

</fragment>
```